# Upgrade to PHP 5.4.29 (from 5.3?) broke my regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My host just upgrade PHP the 5.4.29 from one of the 5.3 versions, I believe.  This broke a very important regular expression that I use in a frequently used program.

I want to match variations on the following (each line is a separate example:

```
1 / AGGRAVATED ASSAULT                                              Withdrawn                                                18 § 2702  
1 / Simple Assault                                                      Guilty Plea                                    18 § 2701 §§ A  
1 / Criminal Mischief                                                  Judgment of Acquittal                            18 § 3304-12
```

This is my regex.  It has worked for the last 2 years without fail:

```
/\d\s+\/\s+(.+)\s{12,}(\w.+?)(?=\s\s)\s{12,}(\w{0,2})\s+(\w{1,2}\s?\247\s?\d+(\-|\247|\w+)*)/
```

I use it as follows:

```
if (preg_match(self::$chargesSearch2, $line, $matches))
```

My expectation is that
matches[1] = the charge (Aggravated assault, etc...)
matches[2] = the grading (which often doesn't appear and isn't on any of these examples)  matches[3] = the disposition (Withdrawn, etc...)
matches[4] = the code section (18 § 2702)

For some reason it doesn't work now--it doesn't match the lines in question.  Does anyone see the error?

Comment: What function are you using? How do you know that it is the regex and not something else that is causing the problem? What is the desired output? What is the actual (undesired) output?

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for this job anyway.

Comment: @RahilWazir I rolled back your edit because the whitespace *is significant*. Without it, `\s{12,}` wouldn't hope to match the string.

Comment: Edit to put in the function that I'm using (preg_match) and the desired output.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol - what is the correct tool for this?  Ah - I see below.  See my comment.

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work now" mean? What _is_ happening?

Comment: @PatrickQ - I edited to answer your question.  The regex doesn't match the line at all whereas it previously did match the line.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot answer the question of why it doesn't work any more, I can tell you that regex is not the right tool for this job. It's kind of like using a flat-headed screwdriver to drive cross-headed screws. Sure, it'll work, but it's easier to use the right tool.

In this case, you should make some kind of basic parser.

```
$line = "1 / AGGRAVATED ASSAULT    ...";
list($count, $rest) = explode("/", $line, 2);
$count = intval(trim($count));

list($crime, $verdict, $details) = explode("     ",$rest);
$crime = trim($crime);
$verdict = trim($verdict);
$details = trim($details);

// I don't know what the significance of the $details are.
// But using the above you should be able to figure out how to parse it :)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Although I agree with you that regex is not the best tool for this specific problem, it seems to be the best tool for the overall task that I have.  I am parsing a much larger document with all sorts of information in it.  Some lines look like this one, but many other lines look different and have very different information in them.  Sadly, I have written a kludgy parser that has a lot of if, else if, else if with lots of regular expressions.  I check each line to see if it contains a basic piece of information I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, I haven't thought enough about this answer, but I think it doesn't do a good enough job with variations.  For example, sometimes these is an "M" or "M1" or "F" stuck in between the crime and the disposition, which is the reason for (\w{0,2}).  A parser like yours couldn't handle that difference, right?

Comment: Nope. But ideally, you should have a better way of inputting stuff. Keep separate data separate. I would expect a parser like this to be used as a one-time tool to get that raw data into something usable.

Comment: That's correct - I wish I were the one inputting the data!  This program is taking information from public criminal record docket sheets put out by the court in PDF form and is parsing it for use in generating legal forms for the defendants.  So the form that I am reading from is what it is.  I have no control over it.  I do capture the information and put it into a database for later use.